# How to merge two files based on the matching of columns?

Tags: python, shell, unix

I have two files out of which I want to create a third which contains all the information and each column is separated by tab.

## file 1:

```
67      rule_ref: _avc ,output_tag: 'hello'
2       rule_ref: _cdf ,output_tag: 'hi'
334     rule_ref: _xyz ,output_tag: 'bye'
1       rule_ref: _abc ,output_tag: 'go'
```

## file 2:

```
rule_ref: _avc ,output_tag: 'hello'     1
rule_ref: _cdf ,output_tag: 'hi'        4
rule_ref: _xyz ,output_tag: 'bye'    5
```

And would like a *file3* such that:

```
67    1    rule_ref: _avc ,output_tag: 'hello'
2     4    rule_ref: _cdf ,output_tag: 'hi'
334   5    rule_ref: _xyz ,output_tag: 'bye'
1     0    rule_ref: _abc ,output_tag: 'go'
```

2nd column of file1 match to 1st column of file2 and file3 contains
1st column from file1, 2nd column from file2 and 3rd column from file1.

I search on google but don't find any result to solve this. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to tell, given the way that SO eats tabs, what your columns are. Another character would make it a lot easier.

Based on your description, though, in the first file I think the numbers are one column and `rule_ref: _avc ,output_tag: 'hello'` etc. the second? And similar for the second file? But you mention the third column of the first file, which doesn't exist with that scheme. Did you mean the second?

If so...

```
$ join -t $'\t' -1 2 -2 1 -a 1 -e 0 -o '1.1 2.2 1.2' <(sort -t $'\t' -k 2 file1.txt) <(sort -t $'\t' -k 1 file2.txt)
1   0   rule_ref: _abc ,output_tag: 'go'
67  1   rule_ref: _avc ,output_tag: 'hello'
2   4   rule_ref: _cdf ,output_tag: 'hi'
334 5   rule_ref: _xyz ,output_tag: 'bye'
```

(`join` requires that the files it joins are sorted on the appropriate field, which your examples aren't, hence the sorting. Also requires a shell like bash that understands `$'\t'`.)

Answer (score 0):

First, i assume you are using *Pandas Dataframe*, then u just need to use merge.

Try this:

```
file1.merge(file2, on='Column with same values', left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey')
```

Doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: No i am not using **Pandas** 
Thanks for the reply @Lucas